# How to improve the speed when I index the numpy array in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

```
h5id_unique = np.unique(df_[:,0])
cnt_nan = 0
cnt_pos = 0
cnt_neg = 0
cnt = 0
for h5id in h5id_unique:
    dfq_ = df_[df_[:,0]==h5id]
    if dfq_.shape[0] <=2 or dfq_[:,1].sum() != 1:
        cnt_nan += 1
        continue
    cnt += 1
    pos_score = dfq_[dfq_[:,1]==1, 2]
    neg_score = dfq_[dfq_[:,1]==0, 2]
    for i in neg_score:
        if i <= pos_score:
            cnt_pos += 1
        else:
            cnt_neg +=1
    if cnt % 500 == 0:
        print cnt_pos / float(cnt_neg), cnt_nan, cnt
```

I have a numpy array named df_,  which has three columns

```
h5id, label, pred
```

`h5id` is an id of string format while the `label` is 0/1 int and the `pred` is a float. Here is my codes. df_ has 11 millions rows while there are 3 million distinct h5id in the array.
I find that my code is very slow. How can I improve it? I think the index operations takes too much time. It will index for 3 million times.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions without fully understanding your code or the data it's running on.
You can try sorting `df_` according to the first column, then you can do smarter indexing based on the fact that identical keys will be next to each other.

Depending on the data, the following code you use suggests an easier approach

```
if dfq_.shape[0] <=2 or dfq_[:,1].sum() != 1:
    cnt_nan += 1
    continue
```

This is filtering out any rows where the identifier occurs two times or less, and any row where the sum of columns one and two does not equal 1. If most of the data does not meet these conditions it will be much faster to filter the data according to these conditions, then process the remainder.  The following pseudo-code gives a rough approach to the filtering

```
vals, idx, count = unique(0.5+randint(2, size=10), return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
cond1 = (count[idx] > 2)
cond2 = (abs(sum(df_[:, 1:], axis=1) - 1) < 1e-9)

newdf = df_[cond1 & cond2]
```

Then process `newdf` the same way as `df_`